# Declaring moveit robot model in header file

Tags: c++, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I am new to C++ with ROS and would love to get some help. Currently, I am trying to write a C++ class object. In the class, I want to share a moveit robot model so I can use it among different function. Like this:

robot.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <moveit/robot_model_loader/robot_model_loader.h>
#include <moveit/robot_model/robot_model.h>
#include <moveit/robot_state/robot_state.h>
#include "robot.h"

LoadRobot::LoadRobot()
{
    // Load robot model
  robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader("robot_description");
  robot_model::RobotModelPtr kinematic_model = robot_model_loader.getModel();

}

void LoadRobot::create_group(){
 const robot_state::JointModelGroup* joint_model_group = kinematic_model->getJointModelGroup("panda_arm");

//do something with joint_model_group ...
}
```

robot.h

```
#ifndef _ROBOT
#define _ROBOT

class LoadRobot{
public:
    LoadRobot();
    void create_group();
};
#endif
```

However, the LoadRobot constructor cannot pass `kinematic_model` to `create_group()`. What should I do instead? Should I put what's in the constructor to the header file and make them private?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327903/declaring-moveit-robot-model-in-header-file/) by [Kolohe113](https://answers.ros.org/users/36311/kolohe113/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is purely a C++ question. In the future it would be best if you'd post these on a forum dedicated to C++ questions.

In this particular case:

> ```
> LoadRobot::LoadRobot()
> ```

```
{
    // Load robot model
  robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader("robot_description");
  robot_model::RobotModelPtr kinematic_model = robot_model_loader.getModel();
}
```

the problem here is that `kinematic_model` is a variable defined and declared in the local scope of `LoadRobot`.

As soon as that scope exits (ie: ceases to exist), it will destroy all variables declared in it, including `kinematic_model`.

`kinematic_model` simply doesn't exist any more in `create_group()`.

> Should I put what's in the constructor to the header file and make them private?

I'm not sure I entirely understand what you mean by this, but one option could be to make `kinematic_model` a member variable indeed, and then initialise it in the constructor. At that point it would be part of a scope other than the local one of `LoadRobot` and persist to be used by `create_group()`.

But again: this is purely a C++ related question. The fact that ROS classes are being used (or more precisely: MoveIt) does not factor in here.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0